# The derivative of the inverse of a function is a the reciprocal of the derivative of the function at the point

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

So, here's what I'm trying to prove:

Let $f$ be a bijective function defined on a subset of the real numbers, with inverse given by $\phi$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in Dom(f)$ so that $f'(x) \neq 0$. Suppose that $\phi$ is continuous at $y = f(x)$. Then, $\phi$ is differentiable at $y = f(x)$ and:

$$\phi'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$

---

Proof Attempt:

The fact that $f$ is bijective guarantees the existence of the inverse function $\phi$. Now, consider the following limit:

$$\phi'(y) = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{\phi(y+\Delta y)-\phi(y)}{\Delta y}$$

where $y = f(x)$ and $y + \Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)$. Since $f$ is injective, $\Delta y \neq 0$. Now, we can rewrite the limit above as:

$$\phi'(y) = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{(x+ \Delta x)-x}{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}$$

$$\phi'(y) = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}$$

Now, we need to show that $\Delta y \to 0$ iff $\Delta x \to 0$. By the continuity of $f$ at $x$, which follows from its differentiability at $x$, we conclude that $\Delta x \to 0 \implies \Delta y \to 0$.

Suppose that $\Delta y \to 0$. Then:

$$\lim_{\Delta y \to 0} \Delta x = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0}[(x+\Delta x)-x] = \lim_{\Delta y \to 0} [\phi(y+\Delta y)-\phi(y)]$$

The limit above is 0 because $\phi$ is continuous at $y = f(x)$. So, it follows that $\Delta y \to 0 \implies \Delta x \to 0$. Using this, we re-write the expression for $\phi'(y)$:

$$\phi'(y) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}}$$

$$\phi'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$

where the limit exists because of the limit law for quotients, which applies because $f'(x) \neq 0$. This proves that $\phi$ is differentiable at $y = f(x)$ and also proves that the formula for computing it holds.

Does the proof above work? If not, why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I want to do it from first principles haha.

Comment: Not particularly sure how this would be done with the chain rule. We would have to differentiate $\phi(f(x))$. The issue is that the differentiability of $\phi$ at $y = f(x)$ is what we have to prove, since that's a condition for the chain rule.

Comment: The proof seems correct to me.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much :D

Comment: You have the right general idea, but you are too cavalier in introducing and handling $\Delta x$. You need to *define* $\Delta x = \phi(y + \Delta y) - x = \phi(y + \Delta y)- \phi(y)$, then the equation $y+\Delta y = f(x + \Delta x)$ follows. You also only need $\Delta y \to 0 \implies \Delta x \to 0$. The other direction (though true) is not useful.

Comment: So if I were to explicitly state that in my proof, it would be fine? I thought that it would be obvious what $\delta x$ would be but you're right, it doesn't seem to be obvious at all if I don't explicitly spell it out.